# How does browser download binary files?

Tags: http, browser

When I click on a binary file (image files, PDF files, videos files etc) in a browser to download, does the server return these files in an HTTP response body? Does HTTP protocol support binary HTTP response body in the first place? Or does the browser uses some other protocol internally to transfer these files?

Any reference (books, links) on how browser works would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Does HTTP protocol support binary HTTP response body in the first place?

Yes. I believe the browser knows it is binary because of the Content-Type header in the response.

In the image below, captured from Wireshark, the data highlighted in blue is binary.
You can see this data is in the body of the response of an HTTP request for an `image/x-icon`.

[image: Wireshark]